# How to query 2 different Sum function at single column with subtract operator on MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables `LG_060_CLCARD` and `LG_060_04_STFICHE`. First table have client informations order by LOGICALREF column. I want to show all customers sales amount (from STFICHE table TOTALDISCOUNTED column) by some criteria. There are some strugle that I wouldt achive. Here my sql codes:

```
SELECT CL.LOGICALREF,
       (ISNULL (IRS04.TOTALDISCOUNTED,0)) AS TOTALDISCOUNTED,
FROM LG_060_CLCARD CL
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CLIENTREF, SUM(TOTALDISCOUNTED) AS TOTALDISCOUNTED
           FROM LG_060_04_STFICHE
           WHERE GRPCODE = 2 AND TRCODE IN (7,8)
           GROUP BY CLIENTREF) IRS04
    ON IRS04.CLIENTREF = CL.LOGICALREF
ORDER BY CL.LOGICALREF
```

I want to sum `STFICHE.TOTALDISCOUNTED` column values which `STFICHE.TRCODE` values are (7,8) and also sum same `STFICHE.TOTALDISCOUNTED` column values which `STFICHE.TRCODE` values are (2,3) and subtract secont one (2,3) value from the first one (7,8). This new value will be my clients sales amount.

My code gives correct result for first part (sum of 7,8 criteria) but I couldnt combine the other criteria.

My second problem is filter this values in date range. For example; I want to show sales amount which contains only June of 2019 (from `STFICHE.DATE` column). How can I add this condition to same sql?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data, in tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements, and your expect results please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can try with add another left join in your query, just like this:

```
    SELECT CL.LOGICALREF,
        (ISNULL(IRS04.TOTALDISCOUNTED,0) - ISNULL(IRS04_2.TOTALDISCOUNTED,0)) AS TOTALDISCOUNTED
    FROM LG_060_CLCARD CL
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT CLIENTREF, SUM(TOTALDISCOUNTED) AS TOTALDISCOUNTED
            FROM LG_060_04_STFICHE
            WHERE GRPCODE = 2 AND TRCODE IN (7,8)
            GROUP BY CLIENTREF) IRS04
        ON IRS04.CLIENTREF = CL.LOGICALREF
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT CLIENTREF, SUM(TOTALDISCOUNTED) AS TOTALDISCOUNTED
            FROM LG_060_04_STFICHE
            WHERE GRPCODE = 2 AND TRCODE IN (2,3)
            GROUP BY CLIENTREF) IRS04_2
        ON IRS04_2.CLIENTREF = CL.LOGICALREF
    ORDER BY CL.LOGICALREF
```

Or you can use with query like this:

```
    SELECT CL.LOGICALREF,
        (ISNULL(IRS04.TOTALDISCOUNTED_1,0) - ISNULL(IRS04.TOTALDISCOUNTED_2,0)) AS TOTALDISCOUNTED
    FROM LG_060_CLCARD CL
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            CLIENTREF, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN TRCODE IN (7,8) THEN TOTALDISCOUNTED ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALDISCOUNTED_1,
            SUM(CASE WHEN TRCODE IN (2,3) THEN TOTALDISCOUNTED ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALDISCOUNTED_2,
        FROM LG_060_04_STFICHE
        WHERE GRPCODE = 2
        GROUP BY CLIENTREF
    )IRS04 ON CL.LOGICALREF=IRS04.CLIENTREF
```

2. For your second problem, I usually use `YEAR` and `MONTH` function, for example:

```
   SELECT * FROM LG_060_04_STFICHE WHERE YEAR([DATE])='2019' AND MONTH([DATE])='6'
```

Or to get data with range between 2 date, you can use `BETWEEN` statement, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM LG_060_04_STFICHE WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was exactly what I want to. It works for both logic and date problems.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a case statement here -

```
SELECT CL.LOGICALREF,
       (ISNULL (IRS04.TOTALDISCOUNTED,0)) AS TOTALDISCOUNTED,
FROM LG_060_CLCARD CL
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CLIENTREF, SUM(CASE WHEN TRCODE IN (7,8) THEN TOTALDISCOUNTED
                                      WHEN TRCODE IN (2,3) THEN TOTALDISCOUNTED*-1
                                 END) AS TOTALDISCOUNTED
           FROM LG_060_04_STFICHE
           WHERE GRPCODE = 2
           AND STFICHE.DATE BEETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31'
           GROUP BY CLIENTREF) IRS04
    ON IRS04.CLIENTREF = CL.LOGICALREF
ORDER BY CL.LOGICALREF
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to:

A = SUM (TRCODE IN (7,8) THEN TOTALDISCOUNTED),
B = SUM (TRCODE IN (2,3) THEN TOTALDISCOUNTED),
RESULT = A-B (A minus B)

Comment: @mithderler, Can you just give it a try now. I forgot to use -1. I am pretty sure this is shorter logic than the accepted answer.